# Cannot connect to RPi 3 with Mac Finder, but can SSH

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ssh

I have tried to make a Mac Time Capsule using my Raspberry Pi 3 with instructions from this(these, they are basically the same) sites:

http://www.howtogeek.com/276468/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-networked-time-machine-drive-for-your-mac/

http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/how-to-make-a-mac-time-capsule-with-the-raspberry-pi-1319989

However, when I try to connect to the Rpi from my Mac using Finder, the [connection fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVehK.jpg).

I can SSH into the Pi though, so I am thinking it has something to do with some settings on the Pi.

I use the Pi as a DNS Server and run Pihole on it.  My Mac runs Sierra, and I connect to the pi using SSH keys.

How can I get the connection to the Pi working from my Mac?

Comment: Witch OS version?

Comment: MacOS Sierra and Raspbian Jessie 8.0